# How to Dynamically Update or replace Android App Strings.xml file with the new file

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-developer-api

I have given multi-language support to my Android App, but I want to add a feature such that the existing strings.xml can be replaced with the new strings.xml for the particular language received from the server.

I could not find much support or resources for this. I just want to dynamically update the strings.xml.

Comment: This only works if you don't use the Android strings and localization system. So you would have to build your own localization system or use an existing Java/Kotlin library but you would still need to manually manage the string file(s) in the app private file-system and also load the strings when required.

Comment: Thanks @Robert yes i think it will required manual intervention , it think it will be much better to provide a new update on playstore for this.

Answer (score 1):

In short, **you can't.**

Without building a **new** updated APK and deploying in the Play Store, you can't directly update your resources (photos, videos, sounds, strings etc..).

The only thing you can do to dynamically use strings in your application is to create an API service and use the strings from the API to load your strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, what you can do is to create placeholders for each labels and fetch the strings in desired languages from the server.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to update existing string xml file in your application without updating app, one solution is to take support from api to get all localized string and render UI with that response or you can also use Firebase Remote Config for this support.